# How to pass jar file (from Artifactory) in dcos spark run?

Tags: jar, pyspark, dcos, spark-submit

I'm trying to run spark streaming job on DC/OS platform and I've got issue with kafka packages. When I'm trying to include Kafka library and its dependencies (jar file downloaded from Maven, added to artifactory and read from there) with the use of `--jars` mode as follows:

```
dcos spark run --submit-args"--jars https://../../../spark-streaming 2.11-2.2.1.jar --conf spark.executor.memory=2g --py-files=https://../../../libs.zip,https://../../../test.py etc"
```

it seems that file `libs.zip`, test.py are correctly read but `.jar` file is omitted.

Any idea why? Is there any workaround for this kind of issue?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the `dcos spark submit` command doesn't support `--jar` option, but you can use the `spark.mesos.uris` [property](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#configuration) to download artifacts to the working directory of a Spark driver and executor.

I'm not sure how your Python-based Spark job is going to use JARs, but you may need setting the `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath` [configuration property](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties) as well.