# How do I use JARs stored in Artifactory in spark submits?

Tags: artifactory, spark-submit

I am trying to configure the spark-submits to use JARs that are stored in artifactory.
I've tried a few ways to do this

- Attempt 1: Changing the `--jars` parameter to point to the https end point

  - Result 1: 401 Error. Credentials are being passed like so: https://username:password@jfrog-endpoint. The link was tested using wget and it authenticates and downloads the JAR fine.
    [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG8U5.png)
- Attempt 2: Using a combination of `--packages`  `--repositories`

  - Result 2: URL doesn't resolve to the right location of the jar
- Attempt 3:Using combination of `--packages` and modified ivysettings.xml (containing repo and artifact pattern)
  [ivy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xl85.png)

  - Result 3: URL resolves correctly but still results in "Not Found"
    After some research it looks like the error might say "Not Found" and the it looks like it has "tried" the repo, it could still very well be a 401 error.
    [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8fSf.png)

Any ideas would be helpful! Links i've explored:

- [Can i do spark-submit application jar directly from maven/jfrog artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956582/can-i-do-spark-submit-application-jar-directly-from-maven-jfrog-artifactory)
- [spark resolve external packages behind corporate artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672403/spark-resolve-external-packages-behind-corporate-artifactory)
- [How to pass jar file (from Artifactory) in dcos spark run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370178/how-to-pass-jar-file-from-artifactory-in-dcos-spark-run)
- https://godatadriven.com/blog/spark-packages-from-a-password-protected-repository/
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://username:password@jfrog.com/rep, however you need to specify port.
https://username:password@jfrog.com:443/repo

I discovered this using Artifactory's "set me up" tool for package type Ivy. If you look in the resolver url it specifies the port.

Comment: tried this still getting 401